# Illuminated Cloud 2 claims that the sfdx executable does not exist or is not executable in my Linux install, why?

Tags: salesforcedx, ide, illuminatedcloud

When adding the path provided by `which sfdx` to the little popup after creating a SFDX project in Illuminated Cloud I get the following error:

> The configured Salesforce CLI executable does not exist or is not executable

But why if that is the executable used by the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the file pointed by `which` is of the alias added by Yarn. The executable it self is in a different folder, like `/home/[your user]/.yarn/bin`.

To get the path to the actual SFDX executable you have to use Yarn's `bin` command to output the location of that file (adding `global` after Yarn in case of a global installation of SFDX, which I believe is most cases):

```
$ yarn global bin sfdx-cli
/home/[your user]/.yarn/bin
```

So the path to be added to Illuminated Cloud's popup is that output with `/sfdx` appended at the end:

`/home/[your user]/.yarn/bin/sfdx`